# Haskell No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of ‘round’

Tags: haskell

Пытался сделать функцию для численного подсчета интеграла. В данном случае для параболы.

```
parabola :: Integer -> Integer
parabola x = x ^ 2

step :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
step b a n = round ((b-a)/n)

linspace :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
linspace b a n = [a,(a + (step b a n))..b]

tintegral :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> a -> Integer
tintegral b a n func = (b - a)*(sum [func x | x <- (linspace b a n)])/n
```

Но получаю несколько ошибок при импорте.

```
test.hs:46:14: error:
• No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of ‘round’
• In the expression: round ((b - a) / n)
  In an equation for ‘step’: step b a n = round ((b - a) / n)
   |
46 | step b a n = round ((b-a)/n)
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

test.hs:46:21: error:
• No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
• In the first argument of ‘round’, namely ‘((b - a) / n)’
  In the expression: round ((b - a) / n)
  In an equation for ‘step’: step b a n = round ((b - a) / n)
    |
 46 | step b a n = round ((b-a)/n)
    |                     ^^^^^^^

  test.hs:52:38: error:
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> Integer’
              with actual type ‘a’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      tintegral :: forall a.
                   Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> a -> Integer
    at test.hs:51:1-58
 • The function ‘func’ is applied to one argument,
  but its type ‘a’ has none
  In the expression: func x
  In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely
    ‘[func x | x <- (linspace b a n)]’
• Relevant bindings include
    func :: a (bound at test.hs:52:17)
    tintegral :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> a -> Integer
      (bound at test.hs:52:1)
   |
52 | tintegral b a n func = (b - a)*(sum [func x | x <- (linspace b a n)])/n
   |                                      ^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Что лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько ошибок:

**Во-первых**, вы почему-то пытаетесь всё делать в целых числах, но при этом используете функции, предназначенные для чисел дробных.

Напрмер, оператор деления `/`. Если вы посмотрите на [его определение](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.0/base-4.10.1.0/Prelude.html#v:-47-), то увидите, что он определён в классе `Fractional` - то есть он будет работать с аргументами любого типа, для которого определён этот класс. Для типа `Integer` класс `Fractional` не определён, поэтому оператор деления `/` с типом `Integer` работать не может. Именно это пытается вам сказать компилятор:

```
 No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
```

Буквальный перевод на русский:

```
 Не могу найти определение класса `Fractional Integer`, которое необходимо для `/`
```

Если вы действительно хотите всё делать в целых числах, то используйте [функцию целочисленного деления `div`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.0/base-4.10.1.0/Prelude.html#v:div):

```
(b-a) `div` n
```

Если же вы имели в виду числа дробные, то замените тип `Integer` на `Float` во всех ваших функциях, кроме количества шагов, которое должно быть целым по логике (но и для него лучше использовать тип `Int` - он быстрее).

В обоих случаях вам вообще не нужен `round`: если вы воспользуетесь функцией `div`, то её результат будет уже целым; если же вы перейдёте на дробные числа, то и округлять незачем.

**Во-вторых**, четвёртый аргумент функции `tintegral` у вас почему-то имеет тип `a`. Так обозначается "общий" тип. Такая запись означает: "*я написал такую функцию, которая будет работать с любым типом `a`; какой тип ей ни дадите, с любым работать будет*".

Но при этом в теле функции вы пытаетесь этот параметр использовать как функцию: `func x`. Запись вида `x y` в Хаскеле означает "*вызов функции `x` с параметром `y`*". Из этого компилятор может заключить, что `func` - это функция. Далее, компилятор смотрит на переменную `x` и видит, что она пришла из списка `linspace b a n`, который имеет тип `[Integer]`, следовательно сама переменная `x` имеет тип `Integer`. Далее, компилятор видит, что вы пытаетесь передать результаты вывозов `func x` в функцию `sum`, а её результат умножить на `(b-a)`. Поскольку `b-a` имеет тип `Integer`, то и умножать его можно только на другой `Integer`, следовательно результат вызова `sum` тоже должен быть `Integer`, а значит каждый вызов `func x` тоже должен вернуть `Integer`. Отсюда видно, что `func` должна быть не просто функцией, а конкретно функцией `Integer -> Integer`. Но в заголовке функции `tintegral` вы определили этот тип как просто `a`. Компилятор видит несоответствие и не знает, что делать:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> Integer’
with actual type ‘a’
```

Буквальный перевод на русский:

```
Ожидаемый здесь тип `Integer -> Integer` не совпадает с
предоставленным типом `a`
```

И далее следует подсказка (здесь компилятор пытается *угадать*, в чём может быть дело):

```
The function ‘func’ is applied to one argument,
but its type ‘a’ has none
```

Буквальный перевод:

```
Функция `func` вызвана с одним аргументом, 
но нё тип `a` не имеет аргументов вовсе.
```

Из контекста я понимаю, что `func` - это есть функция, интеграл которой вы пытаетесь вычислить. В таком случае её тип должен быть просто `Integer -> Integer`:

```
tintegral :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
```

Ну, или, если вы решите таки перейти на дробные числа, то `Float -> Float`:

```
tintegral :: Float -> Float -> Int -> (Float -> Float) -> Float
```

**В-третьих**, чтобы не запутаться во всех этих `Integer` (или `Float`), которые просто везде, я рекомендую определить синонимы для них. Тогда заголовки функций будут лучше читаться и передавать смысл функций.

**Итак,** подытоживая всё вышесказанное, вот как я переписал бы вашу программу:

```
parabola :: Float -> Float
parabola x = x ^ 2

type Point = Float
type IntervalStart = Point
type IntervalEnd = Point
type Step = Float
type Divisions = Int

step :: IntervalStart -> IntervalEnd -> Divisions -> Step
step b a n = (b-a) / fromIntegral n

linspace :: IntervalStart -> IntervalEnd -> Divisions -> [Point]
linspace b a n = [a,(a + step b a n)..b]

tintegral :: IntervalStart -> IntervalEnd -> Int -> (Point -> Float) -> Float
tintegral b a n func = (b - a) * sum [func x | x <- linspace b a n] / fromIntegral n
```